# Is there a flag to request all extended permissions for Facebook authorization?

Tags: facebook, authorization

When a user tries to connect to our app through Facebook, I want to request all extended permissions. Rather than adding every one of [these](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) flags, is there a flag or some other way that I can just say "request everything"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No (and this is intentional). Ask for the data you'll actually need.